# lost file after do "mv" file in filename.sh

Tags: mv

I try to run filename.sh which contains:

```
mv /home/newdir/test1.jpg /home/backupdir
mv /home/newdir/test2.jpg /home/backupdir
mv /home/newdir/test3.jpg /home/backupdir
mv /home/newdir/test4.jpg /home/backupdir
mv /home/newdir/test5.jpg /home/backupdir
```

after that, my test.jpg file is not located on `/home/backupdir`, and that has 2 backupdir:

backupdir and 'backupdir'$'\r'

Then I try to "cd" to 'backupdir'$'\r' but the result is:

bash: cd: $'backupdir\r': Not a directory

Any can help me, please? or maybe have the same issue as me?

Comment: Unfortunately if your script was written with Windows line endings (CRLF in place of plain LF) and there wasn't a pre-existing directory named `/home/backupdir\r` then you likely created and then overwrote the same file multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `/` to the end of your `mv` commands. I think whats happening is you're creating a file named `backupdir` with the contents of `test*.jpg`, and then overwriting it many times.

Also, you can use wildcards instead of running many commands.

```
mv /home/newdir/test*.jpg /home/backupdir
```

If this dosent work please answer:

- What is in `newdir`?
- Is this script being run as root?
- Post the `ls` of your home directory.